# passing parameters to a stored procedure in C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, parameter-passing

How can i send three parameters a to stored procedure in sql?

**Here is my error**: Procedure or function GetIslemIdleri has too many arguments specified.

**This is my stored procedure:**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetIslemDetayIdleri 

@islemId int,
@dovizTanim nvarchar(10),
@yapilanIslemTuru nvarchar(20)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT ([t0].[TOPLAMTUTAR]) + ([t0].[KDVTUTAR]) AS [value]
FROM [dbo].[TBLP1ISLEMDETAY] AS [t0]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[TBLP1ISLEM] AS [t1] ON [t1].[ID] = [t0].[ISLEM_ID]
WHERE ([t0].[ISLEM_ID] = @islemId) AND 
      ([t0].[FIYATBIRIM] = @dovizTanim) AND 
      ([t1].[YAPILANISLEM] = @yapilanIslemTuru) AND 
      ([t0].[KDVDAHILMI] = 0)
END
```

**Here is my code:**

```
        decimal kurToplamQuery = 0;
        string connString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LocalSqlServer1"].ConnectionString;

        SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(connString);
        sqlConn.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd;

        cmd = new SqlCommand("GetIslemIdleri", sqlConn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@islemId", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = islemId;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@dovizTanim", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = dovizTanim;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@yapilanIslemTuru", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = yapilanIslemTipi;

        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())*//error occurs here*
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                kurToplamQuery = reader.GetDecimal(0);                    
            }
        }
        sqlConn.Close();
        return kurToplamQuery;
```

Thanks for your helps.

Comment: Is the problem that you're not calling the stored procedure that posted? They have different names.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The stored procedure is called `GetIslemDetayIdleri` but the code is using a stored procedure called `GetIslemIdleri`.  Maybe the latter has fewer parameters than the former and you meant to call the former in the code?

Comment: @EmreVeriyaz: It happens to the best of us.  Never underestimate the value of a second set of eyes on your code, even if it's just to find the little things.

Answer (score 3):

Your stored procedure: `GetIslemDetayIdleri` have different name then your invocation:

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("GetIslemIdleri", sqlConn);
```

Answer (score 3):

GetIslemDetayIdleri  != GetIslemIdleri

Answer (score 1):

in my case this code is worked .i hope this will work for your case
**Procedure parameter names , type and lenght must be same**
like that

```
       cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@islemId", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = islemId;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@dovizTanim", SqlDbType.NVarChar ,10)).Value = dovizTanim;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@yapilanIslemTuru", SqlDbType.NVarChar,20)).Value = yapilanIslemTipi;
```